# Debugging Authentication attempts against Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, authentication, logging

I have various services configured to authenticate against Active Directory. It would be very helpful if they all logged authentication failures, but they don't. This makes debugging even a simple "incorrect password" error very frustrating.

Is it possible to watch in realtime (or later) authentication attempts against AD?

The AD is Windows Server 2003.

Comment: From where? A linux workstation or a Windows PC? Have you checked out wireshark?

Comment: "From Where" is irrelevant, but in this example, I'm using a web-based bug tracking program. Wireshark won't help because the requests are encrypted with Kerberos. I need logging.

Comment: Are these services/apps authenticating against your DC(s) or another source?

Comment: They are against my domain controllers (is there another way?)

Comment: In the *lovely* K12-software-world we have software that "does AD" by taking a night export from `csvde`.

Comment: We're also using MediaWiki, on Debian, to authenticate against AD. The DC's Security Event Log contains entries of success/failure for these MediaWiki logons, denoting the source address of the server. Are you looking for a way to `tail` or parse the Security EVT?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go with the get-eventlog cmdlet in PowerShell.  This just dumps the latest entry in the application log:

> Get-EventLog -ComputerName foo -LogName application -Newest 1

It just needs tweaking to limit it to authentication events and sources (-source), and to run it against a list of servers.  Maybe schedule it to dump in daily or hourly increments (-after [time])?  I'm clearly no scripting genius but it's what I've got.  ;)